# How do I run localhost server then open the browser in one batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm just exploring batch files to avoid unnecessary typing. First, I set up the localhost server, then attempt to open the browser to access the local server. The batch file opens and starts the server, but then stops there. (it doesn't perform the open browser command) batch file looks like this:

```
cd C:\directory
py -m http.server
start /max http://localhost:8000
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

The problem is that once you start the python server, it keeps running, not stopping to run the open browser command.

### The Solution

So you have to run the open browser command **before** the python server command.

### Example

Like this:

```
cd C:\directory
start /max http://localhost:8000
py -m http.server
```

Comment: Why not just use the `START` command to execute `Python`?

Comment: @Squashman you can't use the `START` command to start a python http server. You need to invoke Python itself

Comment: The purpose of the `START` command is mostly for spawning a separate process.  There should be no reason in the world you could not do: `START "" "py.exe" -m http.server`.  The `START` command will work with any program that is deemed executable by the operating system.

Comment: And here is where they discussed it on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1452244/using-start-http-ipaddressport-opens-a-new-command-prompt). Still seeing if I can find a duplicate question and answer on StackOverFlow.